# The Dock keeps opening if mouse is scrolled to the left in Minecraft

Tags: gnome-shell, minecraft, ubuntu-dock

While playing Minecraft 1.14.4 on Ubuntu 18.04, moving the mouse to the left will open the Ubuntu Dock, which is hidden. How do I stop it from happening? This only happens with the newest versions of Minecraft.

The game will also snap back when the Dock is open (the camera perspective will turn to the right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running Minecraft 1.15 on Ubuntu 20.04, but have experienced this problem since Ubuntu 18.04. One less than great solution, which improves (but does not eliminate) the issue:

Increase the pressure required to unhide the dock with the `dconf-editor`. Setting is located at `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/pressure-threshold`, I found that 275.0 is about as much as you can increase it without becoming annoying outside of Minecraft.

But finally it seems there is a better way to do this! Minecraft recently added some new mouse settings to the control menu, and I was able to eliminate the issue entirely by disabling raw input in my Minecraft [mouse settings](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Options#Mouse_Settings). Can also be done by editing `~/.minecraft/options.txt` and setting `rawMouseInput:false`. You can still access the dock with Minecraft maximized by opening the menu and moving your cursor to the dock location, like normal.

Comment: You're not supposed to ask a question in the Answers section. Your answer does provide a couple of workarounds for the problem raised in the original question, which is acceptable. If you have more questions feel free to [ask a new one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) (if needed provide a link to this question for context).